# How to decide on scala Variable Range in for loop

Tags: scala, for-loop

The codes to be compared:

```
val distance = List(1,2,3)
distance.foreach(println)
var posA:Int = 2
var posB:Int = 2
var tmp:Int = 0
var result:Long = 0
var foundDis = false        
 for(dis <- distance ){
  if(tmp == posA && posA == posB){
    result = dis
    foundDis = true
    record.distance = result
    println(record.distance)
  }
  tmp += 1
}
println("result:record.distance" + record.distance)
```

在这里两次println输出同样的数值，但是如果distance换成下面，第一个println正常输出，第二个输出0

```
val distance = graphFile.map(s => (s.split(",")(4).toLong,1)) 
distance.foreach(println)
var posA:Int = 2
var posB:Int = 2
var tmp:Int = 0
var result:Long = 0
var foundDis = false        
 for(dis <- distance ){
  if(tmp == posA && posA == posB){
    result = dis
    foundDis = true
    record.distance = result
    println(record.distance)
  }
  tmp += 1
}
```

println("result:record.distance" + record.distance) 
下面这段代码中for循环内的println输出正常，而循环外的println为0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hey i have already solved it
var linkRefs = graphFile.map(s => (s.split(",")(0).toString)).collect